# How did my packages update?

Tags: packages, memoir, gummi

I downloaded the memoir class package and ran the .ins file.

Then, without doing anything else, it seemed that the memoir class was up and running!

I don't think it was there previously....I am running gummi on Ubuntu. How would I verify where the package is?

Does the .ins file automatically transfer the files to the gummi program or....?

Comment: *Where* did you compile (or run) the `.ins` file? You should be able to check your `.log` file and find the line referencing `memoir.cls`, and identify the folder.

Comment: I ran the .ins file from my downloads folder. I only see a log file for when I tried (apparently unsuccessfully) to run the .dtx file. The output of that file is here:http://pastebin.com/aitrssqw

Comment: I meant look at the `.log` file of your successfully-compiled example file that uses `memoir`, not the `.log` file associated with a call to `memoir.ins`.

Comment: oh, yeah, got it. It all went into a /tmp file. I reckon it is ok to leave it there. It seems to work.

Comment: You should read [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764). Also, since you're using TeX Live 2009, it's time for a full update to [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html). For that, also see [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5764) and/or [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu 12.04 also see [*How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) for information about updating through the package manager.